# Whats the difference between ADMX and ADML files?

Tags: windows, server, active-directory

What are the exact difference between ADMX and ADML files? I can't find the exact difference between the two. It's always mentioned in the same sentence on everything i find on google.

Comment: I found the problem. I was searching in Bing, ADML is a settings file for localizations for a correspending ADMX file.

Answer (score -1):

ADML is a localization file for a corresponding ADMX file.

Do not Bing technical questions.